# How to use Google Drive as secure storage on a linux server

Tags: disk-encryption, fuse, google-drive

since google dropped the price for storage recently I thought about using it at my storage servers too add storage capacity easily.

What I found so far is the ability to mount the google drive into a fuse file system using google-drive-ocamlfuse. That woks great but I would like to have encryption for the files leaving my server to the cloud.

The solutions I found are EncFS and Truecrypt. Both need to have the same among of storage on the server as on the e.g google drive. I would like to have a solution where I mount the drive using some type of auth and than can use it like normal space however on google drive the data is crypted.

Comment: EncFS/Truecrypt encrypt a volume. You'd be better off encrypting individual files using GPG and handling encryption/decryption in your app.

Answer (score 1):

I think eCryptfs might be what you are looking for. Ubuntu has come with eCryptfs for many years, and it is very easy to enable it for home directories. For other directories it may require a bit more effort, but `man ecryptfs` should be a good starting point.